# New Box, new to linux, would love advice

Tags: installation, distro-recommendation

Looking for recommendations on best distro for specs. Tried Ubuntu 12.04 and 12.10 and both ran extremely slowly.

- **Motherboard** - Biostar A780L3C
- **Processor** - AMD Anthlon ii X3 445 3.1GHz
- **Memory** - 8Gb Corsair Vengeance DDR3 1600Mhz
- **HDD** - WD 320GB
- **Wireless card** - Rosewill RNX-250PC2 pci card

Also bought a OCZ Vertex 2 80Gb ssd drive with the intention of installing the os on the ssd, and using the WD as file storage, but can't seem to get it to be recognized by ubuntu or even the bios. Figured it was a dud and moved on.

Having great difficulty with the Wireless card as well. Seems to drop support whenever I update the system, but works with the basic install of 12.04 and 12.10.

Comment: I've run Ubuntu 12.04 very fast on much much lower specs. What was running slow? Because your specs should be very fast on any Ubuntu edition...

Comment: cpu mostly from what I can see. Monitor has them running at cpu1: 50%, cpu2 75%, cpu 3 50%. This is at startup before I've run anything else. slows down and seems to crash intermittently when running most things like software update and firefox.

Comment: that doesn't seem right... screenshot? Is the system fully updated with the newest kernels, etc?

Comment: After failing numerous times, finally got all packages to install. Running a little better now with 12.10, but still having some system lag problems. cpu only at 15-20% now on all processors, but that's acceptable by all means for now. Would love any troubleshooting hints for the network card and ssd drive though.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I'm guessing that this laptop is not brand new, considering your hardware. What I did was I opened up my laptop, and I found that my memory (RAM) was really dusty, and loose. I took it out, *carefully*, dusted it off, and put it back. My laptop ran way faster.

Comment: Desktop actually. most of the hardware is just purchased, reused an old tower and 1000W power supply that I had on hand.

Comment: My bad. :D I usually work with laptops.

Comment: no worries ;) ssd problem would be more up your alley though, any advice on troubleshooting it? led light powers on when I install it, but system hangs trying to identify it during boot up, then eventually just gives up.

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: Loose RAM causes boot issues and crashes at the very least (assuming this is even possible, as most modules click in, so either is is inserted or it isn't.  Furthermore, this answer is just a wild guess at something not supported by any evidence.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. I ended up installing 10.04, and it ran like a breeze. I don't know what it is, but my computer (pentium D) just doesn't like ubuntu 11+. Maybe try installing 10.04 LTS. I think it is still supported for a few more days. I could be wrong.